# How to fix google map marker in center?

Tags: html, css

I have a marker in google map and i want it to be always in center (left is also acceptable). now it is in the right corner and on small width it cant be seen. please help!

```
<div class="mapouter">
<div class="gmap_canvas">
<iframe width="1086" height="290" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/mapsq=%E1%83%9B%E1%83%98%E1%83%AA%E1%83%99%E1%83%94%E1%83%95%E1%83%98%E1%83%A9%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1%20%E1%83%A5%E1%83%A3%E1%83%A9%E1%83%90%207%E1%83%90&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</iframe>
<a href="https://www.emojilib.com">emojilib.com</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are supposed to show a reproducible example [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried your code and the maps is aligned to the left with 1086px  width. Show your CSS for mapouter and gmap_canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
      /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
     #map {
       height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
       width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
      }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
   <!--The div element for the map -->
   <div id="map"></div>
   <script>
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
 // The location of Uluru
 var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
 // The map, centered at Uluru
 var map = new google.maps.Map(
     document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
 // The marker, positioned at Uluru
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
   </script>
   <!--Load the API from the specified URL
   * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
   * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
   * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
   -->
   <script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```